# Threshold value based heatmap in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, heatmap, mapbox-gl

We are trying to plot heatmap based on values of air quality sensor devices , Based on what I could find on internet, we can plot heatmap based on density, I saw few examples of Weather API for temperature based heatmap but couldn't find any reference to it.

Only example I could find is  https://github.com/Rylern/TemperatureMap but this is integrated with Open weather API , we would like to do it based on our backend setup. I am unable to find any documentation on how to change color for these, so unable to proceed with this approach too
Any direction or guidance is appreciated.